# New lines in flask within {%block content%}

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So if I were to do something like `{% block content %}
         {{variable}}
         {% endblock %}`
in my HTML, and `variable` is equal to `"Test <br /> test2"` how come the 
 prints out and does not make a new line? is there a way to fix this?

Comment: See the documentation: [HTML Escaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#html-escaping)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jinja2 [automatically escapes special characters](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#controlling-autoescaping) for you. Probably simplest way is to use `safe` filter:

```
{{ variable|safe }}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your output is escaped and you see literal `<br />` text in your browser, switch off autoescaping for the variable:

```
{% block content %}{% autoescape false %} {{variable}} {% endautoescape %}{% endblock %}
```

or tell Jinja2 that the variable is safe for interpolation:

```
{% block content %} {{variable|safe}} {% endblock %}
```