# Insert paragraph from Python Flask to HTML

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask

I'm new to Flask in Python. I've managed to transfer values from my python code to an HTML page. I'm trying to transfer one value which is actually a long paragraph. 
I have a loop creating this long text:

```
google_str += num + '. ' + title + '\n' + url + '\n'
```

I want this to eventually look like this in HTML:

> 1. Title1
>      URL1
> 2. Title2
>      URL2

etc.

I'm sending it to HTML like this:

```
return render_template('searchtool.html', google_str = google_str)
```

But then I see the text as one big paragraph without the new lines. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Found what I was looking for.

First, I had to use "< br >" instead of '/n'.
Second, use this in my HTML:

```
{{google_str|safe}}
```

[This is where I found the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253259/new-lines-in-flask-within-block-content)